# How to download https://github.com/MCMrARM/mcpelauncher-linux?

Tags: deb

I can't download it because it gives me a  404 error. Also, it will say that I need `libprotobuf17` but it isn't installable. Also, I'm using KDE Neon and 64 bit.

Any time I do

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://mcpelauncher.mrarm.io/apt/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

it will say Error 404 and give me some weird IP address. This is what i get:

```
alex@alex-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install msa-daemon msa-ui-qt mcpelauncher-client mcpelauncher-ui-qt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mcpelauncher-client:i386 is already the newest version (20190511-122010-88ad96a~disco).
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) mcpelauncher-ui-qt:amd64 < none -> 20190511-122041-98ac412~disco @un puN Ib >
Broken mcpelauncher-ui-qt:amd64 Depends on libzip5:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken mcpelauncher-ui-qt:amd64 Depends on libprotobuf17:amd64 < none @un H >
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mcpelauncher-ui-qt : Depends: libzip5 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libprotobuf17 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: If you follow that link with a browser you'll end on [this link](https://mcpelauncher.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) which have instructions on how to install it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you've tried to download it, but since it's a Git repository, I suggest downloading it by using the `git` command to clone the repository. To do this, first install `git` if it's not installed:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
```

Then `cd` to whatever directory you want to download it to, and run:

```
git clone https://github.com/MCMrARM/mcpelauncher-linux.git
```

Assuming that succeeds (as it did when I tested it), the downloaded repository consists of the newly created `mcpelauncher-linux` directory and its contents.

---

With that said, if you want to download it in your web browser as a ZIP archive, you can do that. Click the "Clone or download" button and then click the "Download ZIP" link. For this particular repository, that's https://github.com/MCMrARM/mcpelauncher-linux/archive/master.zip.

If these techniques don't work, there might be a problem with your Internet connection (or with your proxy configuration, if you browse the web through a proxy server), or perhaps a transient problem on GitHub (if trying exactly what you did before works now).

Comment: How do i launch it and i also get this error The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mcpelauncher-ui-qt : Depends: libzip5 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libprotobuf17 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: That's an entirely different question, and it means that you have unwisely installed wrong-version packages from non-Ubuntu or wrong-release Ubuntu sources. Uninstall the wrong-version packages and install the correct-version packages.

Comment: i already got it to work i didnt need your help